# KeyEvents for AnchorPane don't work

Tags: javafx

I want to handle the CRTL-Z key combination. I have a Main class that extends `Stage` and inside it I have an `AnchorPane`
I'd like to add to that `AnchorPane` an `EventHandler` for a `KeyPressed` event, but if I do

```
_anchorPane.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Check");
                        KeyCombination ctrlZ = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Z, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
                        if(ctrlZ.match(event))
                            cancelLastShape();
                    }
                });
```

it does nothing. I put there a print function to see if the program "enters" there, but nothing. I tryed to set `_anchorPane.setFocusTraversable(true);`, but it doesn't change anything.
What can I do about it?

Comment: maybe this topic can help you [multiple keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944270/javafx-key-listener-for-multiple-keys-pressed-implementation)

Comment: the problem is not the keys combination, is that the anchorPane doesn't handle the keyevent. I try to catch the Enter button, it doesn't do anything, that's the problem

Comment: Try _anchorPane.requestFocus();

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the listener on the scene : _anchorPane.getScene().addEventHandler();